# JQuery fade out/in animation issue: objects not fading back in

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to write a JQuery version of the dice game Yahtzee as a learning exercise. To roll the dice, the user clicks a button which fires a function handling the entire roll. What's supposed to happen during this process is that any dice which the user has not marked as "locked" are supposed to fade out (animating the css opacity value to 0), after which the dice are 'rolled', and then faded back in.

The method handling this process looks like this:

```
function rollHand() {

    for ( var count = 0; count <= 4; count++) {
        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        var myCell = $( //id of table cell containing current dice object );
        if ( //myCell isn't marked 'locked' ) {
                myCell.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function() {
                    // 'roll' dice
                });
            }
            myCell.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
else {
    // other stuff
}
```

}

There are five dice in play, so this function loops five times. However, dice two, three and four never fade back in and the final fifth dice changes whether it's marked locked or not.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I've found animating table cells to be fraught with difficulties. I'm curious if temporarily swapping the containing element over to a DIV would yield a different result.

Also, you could change the jQuery call to animate the opacity of the "dice" elements inside the TD, rather then animating the cell itself.

Comment: This is a good point but i'm not sure it applies here.  I also have had similar problems with things like show/hide, and fadeIn/fadeOut on table cells because eventually the elements can get styles of "display:none;".  This causes problems like shifting cells across when a preceeding cell gets "hidden" since thats not normally what you want.  But what the OP is doing here is only manipulating the opacity so in theory it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `fadeToggle()` rolling the dice in ints callback?

```
if ( //myCell isn't marked 'locked' ) {
        myCell.fadeToggle(1000, function() {
            // 'roll' dice
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dice isn't locked you are calling both animate to full opacity and empty opacity at the same time.  It will probably give you inconsistent results.  If I understand you correctly, you need to call the show animation once the hide animation has finished.  Like this.

```
function rollHand() {

    for ( var count = 0; count <= 4; count++) {
        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        var myCell = $( "id of table cell containing current dice object" );
        if ( !myCell.is(".locked") ) {
            // Roll dice
            // Start fade out
            myCell.animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000, function() {
                // Dice is now hidden
                // Start fade in
                myCell.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000, function() {
                    // Dice is showing again
                });
            });
        } else {
            // Other stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this change (also suggested by @John S), and it actually made the problem worse. If I leave the second animation outside the function called at the end of the first, the images actually fade back in properly. I get that it shouldn't work this way, yet it does.

Comment: @bmurrell30 - I deleted my answer because it was incorrect. Animations are asynchronous, but I forgot they are queued when applied to the same element. Therefore it works to have it either way.

Comment: @John thanks. Yes of course they are. I totally forgot that.  Since that also make my answer wrong, i will remove this answer soon.